# LaTex table first column, first row not being centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularray

I'm new to LaTex and I'm trying to work on a rather complex table. My table is fine for most of the cells, but the first row, first column (the one I write down "n10", which occupies 3 lines in the table) is not aligned.  Here's my minimum working example (which I tried in overleaf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \footnotesize % Reduce the font size
    \caption{Critérios utilizados para classificação das escalas. (Continuação)}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colsep=4pt,
        colspec = {X[0.5, c] X[1, c] X[2, j] X[0.5, c] X[1, c]}, % Adjust the width of the last column here,
        rows = {font=\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\linespread{0.9}}, % Combine font size settings and specify row alignment
        cells={valign=m}
    }
    \hline \hline

    \SetCell[r=3]{c} n10 & \SetCell[r=3]{c} AVE > .5? & \SetCell[r=3]{j} \strut Average Variance Extracted (AVE), de cada um dos construtos da escala, é superior a .5, sugerindo validade convergente.
    & 1 & AVE dos construtos é > .5 em todos os construtos. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0.5 & AVE dos construtos é <= .5, mas foi calculado. \\
    & & 
    & 0 & AVE não calculado. \\

    \SetCell[r=2]{c} n11 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Correlacionou com medidas alternativas? & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Foi conduzida uma análise de correlação entre a escala proposta e um instrumento alternativo para medir fluxo (ou dimensões associadas), de forma a investigar validade convergente.
    & 1 & Conduziram análise de correlação. \\ 
    & &  
    & 0 & Não conduziram análise de correlação.\\

    \SetCell[r=2]{c} n12 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Interpretou validade convergente? & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Na validação da escala, são interpretados os dados relacionados à validade convergente, considerando os critérios observados em notas anteriores (cargas de fatores, Average Variance Extracted, e comparar a escala com instrumentos alternativos que avaliam fluxo).
    & 1 & Há uma interpretação e discussão dos resultados. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0 & Não há uma interpretação e discussão dos resultados.\\

    \SetCell[r=3]{c} n13 & \SetCell[r=3]{c} Intercorrelação entre itens e fatores distintos é < .85? & \SetCell[r=3]{c} Foi conduzida uma análise da intercorrelação entre itens e fatores distintos, de uma mesma escala ou entre escalas distintas que medem fatores distintos; e itens e fatores distintos não estão excessivamente correlacionados.
    & 1 & Intercorrelações entre itens e fatores distintos é < .85. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0.5 & Intercorrelações entre itens e fatores distintos é >= .85, mas foram calculadas. \\
    & & 
    & 0 & Intercorrelações entre itens e fatores distintos não foram calculadas.\\

    \SetCell[r=2]{c} n14 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Fornell-Larcker criterium & \SetCell[r=2]{c} O critério Fornell-Larcker foi observado, sugerindo validade divergente: foram comparados os valores médios extraídos (AVE) da variância, para quaisquer dois construtos, com o quadrado da estimativa de correlação entre esses dois construtos, e estimativas extraídas da variância (AVE) foram maiores que a estimativa de correlação ao quadrado, para todos os construtos.
    & 1 & Critério Fornell-Larcker foi observado. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0 & Critério Fornell-Larcker não foi observado.\\

    \end{tblr}
    \footnotesize\hfill Continua na próxima página %%
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

oddly enough, this "first cell" of my table seems aligned with the first row, but it's as if my first cell isn't occupying 3 lines in the table.

Please help me.

Comment: please add your example here, not using an external link

Comment: Off-topic: Do please also run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble.

Comment: You are aware of `longtblr`? Then you wouldn't have to manually insert things like "Continua na próxima página"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the empty line before your first cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \footnotesize % Reduce the font size
    \caption{Critérios utilizados para classificação das escalas. (Continuação)}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colsep=4pt,
        colspec = {X[0.5, c] X[1, c] X[2, j] X[0.5, c] X[1, c]}, % Adjust the width of the last column here,
        rows = {font=\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\linespread{0.9}}, % Combine font size settings and specify row alignment
        cells={valign=m}
    }
    \hline \hline
    \SetCell[r=3]{c} n10 & \SetCell[r=3]{c} AVE > .5? & \SetCell[r=3]{j} \strut Average Variance Extracted (AVE), de cada um dos construtos da escala, é superior a .5, sugerindo validade convergente.
    & 1 & AVE dos construtos é > .5 em todos os construtos. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0.5 & AVE dos construtos é <= .5, mas foi calculado. \\
    & & 
    & 0 & AVE não calculado. \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{c} n11 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Correlacionou com medidas alternativas? & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Foi conduzida uma análise de correlação entre a escala proposta e um instrumento alternativo para medir fluxo (ou dimensões associadas), de forma a investigar validade convergente.
    & 1 & Conduziram análise de correlação. \\ 
    & &  
    & 0 & Não conduziram análise de correlação.\\
    \SetCell[r=2]{c} n12 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Interpretou validade convergente? & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Na validação da escala, são interpretados os dados relacionados à validade convergente, considerando os critérios observados em notas anteriores (cargas de fatores, Average Variance Extracted, e comparar a escala com instrumentos alternativos que avaliam fluxo).
    & 1 & Há uma interpretação e discussão dos resultados. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0 & Não há uma interpretação e discussão dos resultados.\\
    \SetCell[r=3]{c} n13 & \SetCell[r=3]{c} Intercorrelação entre itens e fatores distintos é < .85? & \SetCell[r=3]{c} Foi conduzida uma análise da intercorrelação entre itens e fatores distintos, de uma mesma escala ou entre escalas distintas que medem fatores distintos; e itens e fatores distintos não estão excessivamente correlacionados.
    & 1 & Intercorrelações entre itens e fatores distintos é < .85. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0.5 & Intercorrelações entre itens e fatores distintos é >= .85, mas foram calculadas. \\
    & & 
    & 0 & Intercorrelações entre itens e fatores distintos não foram calculadas.\\
    \SetCell[r=2]{c} n14 & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Fornell-Larcker criterium & \SetCell[r=2]{c} O critério Fornell-Larcker foi observado, sugerindo validade divergente: foram comparados os valores médios extraídos (AVE) da variância, para quaisquer dois construtos, com o quadrado da estimativa de correlação entre esses dois construtos, e estimativas extraídas da variância (AVE) foram maiores que a estimativa de correlação ao quadrado, para todos os construtos.
    & 1 & Critério Fornell-Larcker foi observado. \\ 
    & & 
    & 0 & Critério Fornell-Larcker não foi observado.\\
    \end{tblr}
    \footnotesize\hfill Continua na próxima página %%
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! many thanks!It worked! thanks! wow! didn't know this could be  a problem! thanks!

Comment: @FabioPhillip You are welcome!